# Use azure spatial anchor to position your layout in Unity-Hololens

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I am trying to find a way to position my layout when I am detecting a spatial anchor in my Unity-Hololens application. I am currently running quickstarts > MRTK. The app is detecting my uploaded anchor. How can I position the other objects in my scene after detection?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store some additional information related to the anchor you can use properties of CloudSpatialAnchor. Here is a link to ASA documentation related to it:
[CloudSpatialAnchor.AppProperties Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.spatialanchors.cloudspatialanchor.appproperties?view=spatialanchors-dotnet)

It a nutshell it’s a key-value store for any data that is specific to an application.
In this sample application it is used to store object shape information:
[CreationFragment.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples/blob/08e00c61d419e2e322be883f9adf3ee8bf0eb0ed/Xamarin/SampleXamarin.Android/AnchorCreationFragment.cs#L105)

You can store scene relative transform as a property of an anchor and then retrieve it from the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a root object and use as a scene origin. Procedure is like:

1. Create a root object in your scene and parent all the objects to this one.
2. When you create ASA anchor, attach CloudNativeAnchor to this object and save it.
3. In the loading scenario, you can create (or move) your root object with the position and rotation from the found ASA anchor. All the child objects will position accordingly.